# Making simple graphical programs without an X Server (alternatives to svgalib)

Tags: graphics, xorg, application-development, c, shared-library

Is it possible to create simple graphical programs in C without an X Server. I'm talking about svgalib or libsvga. Is there another alternative library? But I can't get it on 16.04 LTS.

I do wish to see how graphics work in linux.

[SVGAlib](http://www.svgalib.org/) and  [SVGAlib Beginners Guide](http://www.svgalib.org/jay/beginners_guide/beginners_guide.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is potentially possible but it's not really frequently done and likely you are heading into murky territory.  Using X in some way is likely a better idea.  Best alternate suggestion I have perhaps is to look at fbdev, found some details here though there are probably better sources:
http://betteros.org/tut/graphics1.php